# PyMongo - Setting all values in an attribute to lowercase

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am cleaning a dataset, and have a field gender. In this field, there are entries such as Male, male, and MALE. To resolve this, I am trying to update my MongoDB database using pymongo.

In the database, the Gender attribute is Gender (which a capital G at the front)

My code currently looks like this:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


db_info = {
    'db_name': 'MentalHealth',
    'collection_name': 'MentalHealth',
}

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mongo_client = MongoClient()
    mongo_db = mongo_client[db_info['db_name']]
    mongo_collection = mongo_db[db_info['collection_name']]

    #normalize to lowercase
    mongo_collection.aggregate([{ '$project': { 'Gender':{ '$toLower':"$Gender"}}}])
```

The code runs without issue, but the database is not updating, and I am unsure what is the error with the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: You are doing an `aggregate` which will return you all `Gender` fields cast to lower case. To update record use [update](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one)

Comment: You are almost there. You have many options. See my answer on the *possible duplicate*

Comment: @sstyvane this is wrong duplicate. OP is not updating `Gender` field using value of another field but the same field.

Comment: Another field or same field, the process is still the same that is why we say "possible duplicate" I would have answered if it was not the case because none of the answers here is useful except this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031117/3100115) which mentioned the `$out` pipeline stage operator. @GarbageCollector

Comment: _Possible Duplicate_ is when you flag a question as duplicate, marking a question as duplicate means both are exact same.
Yes I do agree using `$out` pipeline operator is one way of solving this problem, however whether an answer is useful or not is to be decided by OP. @sstyvane

Comment: You are missing the point here. The answers are not only for the OP.  I raised that [issue once on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313580/what-to-do-with-answers-that-teach-bad-practice) with answers that teach bad practice see this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313580/what-to-do-with-answers-that-teach-bad-practice#comment288104_313581) but I guess you don't want to see what I am pointing out and that is your choice @GarbageCollector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using aggregate query which will return you the result with all `Gender` fields cast to lower case. If you wish to update the value for a field you have to use `update` query.

Since you are using **pymongo** to query your documents your code should be like this

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

db_info = {
    'db_name': 'MentalHealth',
    'collection_name': 'MentalHealth'
}

if __name__ == "__main__":

     mongo_client = MongoClient()
     mongo_db = mongo_client[db_info['db_name']]
     mongo_collection = mongo_db[db_info['collection_name']]

     for doc in mongo_collection.find(no_cursor_timeout=True):
            pk = ObjectId(str(doc.get("_id")))
            g = doc.get('Gender')
            if g:
               g = g.lower()
               mongo_collection.update({"_id": pk}, {"$set":{"Gender":g}})
```

Comment: My [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031026/pymongo-setting-all-values-in-an-attribute-to-lowercase?noredirect=1#comment83046508_48031100) on the answer above applies to your answer as well

Answer (score 5):

Mongodb aggregation operations process data records and return computed results. It can't update any collection. you can update the same like this

```
db.mongo_collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.mongo_collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "Gender": doc.Gender.toUpperCase() } }
    );
});
```

Comment: This question is tagged `pymongo` however your solution is using `js`

Comment: Thank you for your help. As Garbage Collector said, this isn't in python, it is in js, but I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework you’re using only performs queries. To actually perform writes, you need to use a `$out` stage to dump the results into the collection. 
If you select an existing collection, that collection is replaced atomically as described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out

Another option is to use an `update` operation to update just the documents with incorrect case.